# The Review count in top bar shows 10. However there are no review items

Tags: bug, status-completed

For past few days I keep seeing the count of review items as 10. When I click on review there are no item.

Instead of showing a count of Zero, there is a count of 10 ... it increases to 11 or 12 and reduces when I complete the review ... [image]

Comment: Happening to me to.  Actually, 10 is the baseline.  If it says 11 then I have 1 item to review.

Comment: @MrChrister So I am not alone then :) At times the refresh is also not fast ... the count shows 15 and after reviewing 5, it sometimes takes 2-3 mins to go back to 10

Comment: Thanks for loading this note, I thought it might be Mods-only, and wasn't going to post it. Hopefully the code guys/gals will fix it soon.

Comment: @Dheer I imagine the delay in the counter resetting back to 10 is due to caching, but that still doesn't explain why it's 10 in the first place (I see 10 at all times as well).

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say this is a count bug related to the 10 Site Self-Evaluation questions that are loaded up.

Comment: I am stuck at 13 now.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer I was also stuck at 13 for quite few hours and then goes back to Zero. Surprisingly there is no response from SE

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer or other Mods. It's been a week and there is no update from SE on this. Any inputs if they have seen and fix is under way.

Comment: No feedback yet, sorry. It's labeled *bug* and I'd expect someone is working on it.

Comment: I'm making sure this is what I think it is (a caching thing), will post back with a proper answer soon-ish.

Comment: @TimPost There are 2 Issues, One the count is always 10 or more, from 5th May. Second is caching, the count at times is greater than 10 say around 12 or 14 after review does not immediately come down to 10, remains at 11 or 13 and after few hours comes back to 10.

Comment: Any update, guys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be fixed now that the [site evaluation queue has been turned off](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1991/why-is-the-current-site-self-evaluation-still-running/1995#1995).

You might still see counts in the top bar that are "off" since we show the total number of reviews there, not just the number available to you personally, but at least it won't be stuck on the same 10 anymore. :)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This issues seems active again. Any ideas what's up? The list shows no open review items, I just didn't snip the whole screen.

Comment: There were 2 issues. One the base was 10. This was fixed. Second the number of items open for review across all users. This is still open. i.e. if there are 4 items that need review by 2 users, and one user takes action, it will still show 4 for him till some other user takes actions. If you read the answer by Anna Lear.

Comment: Ok. I got it now. I was being dense, now on reading your explanation I get it.