# Why is the current site self-evaluation still running?

Tags: bug, status-completed, site-evaluation

I reviewed a question for the current iteration of the site self-evaluation back on April 23 ([here's the link](https://money.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval/9884)). I notice that the self-evaluation is still running. Isn't this kind of a long time for the self-evaluation to be active? On the other sites where I've used the self-evaluation queue, it's usually gone within a week or two.

I suspect that this might be related to [this bug](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1981/11111) - there are 10 items in the self-evaluation queue, after all.

UPDATE: It's been running for over two months now...

Comment: Looking into this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't run evaluations on graduated sites, and it looks like you guys happened to graduated while an evaluation was running... which threw a wrench into the checks the queue runs to determine if it should close down.

I added a developer-only route to force-close evaluations if necessary, so this is all cleaned up now. Thanks for the report!